# How to properly intercept HTTP error with ErrorInterceptor and create custom errors in Angular10

Tags: angular

I got this Interceptor class

```html
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if ([401, 403].includes(err.status) && this.authenticationService.usagerValue) {
                // auto logout if 401 or 403 response returned from api
                this.authenticationService.logout();
                console.error("LogOut - 403");
            }

            let errorMsg = {};
            if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
                console.log('this is client side error');
                errorMsg = {
                    Error: `${err.error.message}`,
                    Type: `Client`
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log('this is server side error');
                errorMsg = {
                    Error: `${err.error.message}`,
                    Type: `Server`,
                    Code: `${err.status}`,
                    MsgOrig: `${err.message}`
                }
            }
            console.log(errorMsg);
            return throwError(errorMsg);
        }))
    }
}
```

then in my login component:

```html
this.authService.login(this.form.get('username').value, this.form.get('password').value)
.pipe(first())
.subscribe(
    next => { 
        this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
    },
    error => {
        if(error === undefined)
            this.alertService.error("Erreur not defined!", { id: 'alertLogin' })
        else
            this.alertService.error(error.message, { id: 'alertLogin' })
        this.loading = false;
    });
```

But the error variable in loginComponent is always undefined. Why?
If I return the err property (in my interceptor), in my login I can only retrieve the error.message part of the message sent by my web server.
Thanks

Comment: you say the intercepter works from the server just fine ? Are you absolutely sure that the err.error  is instanceof ErrorEvent.

Comment: No, the err.error is not an instance of ErrorEvent because I go to the Else of the IF. But my question is why, when I create a new  errorMsg object  and throw it with ThrowError(errorMsg) the subscribe just receive undefined... DO I have to wrap my errorMsg in something before the throw?

Comment: Finally, I find a way, but I do not understand it. I need to wrap my custom object in another dummy object with error properties. In this case my subscription receives the error :Test = {  error: errorMsg  }